# React functional components in Array.map are always rerendering when getting passed a function as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am trying to render multiple buttons in a parent component that manages all child states centrally. This means that the parent stores e.g. the click state, the disabled state for each button in his own state using `useState` and passes it as props to the childs. Additionally the `onClick` function is also defined inside of the parent component and is passed down to each child. At the moment I am doing this like the following:

```
const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(Array(49).fill(false));
...
const onClick = useCallback((index) => {
     const newIsSelected = [...prev];
     newIsSelected[i] = !newIsSelected[i];
     return newIsSelected;
}, []);
...

(In the render function:)

return isSelected.map((isFieldSelected, key) => {
     <React.Fragment key={key}>
          <TheChildComponent
               isSelected={isFieldSelected}
               onClick={onClick}
          />
     </React.Fragment/>
})
```

To try to prevent the child component from rerendering I am using...

- ... `useCallback` to make react see that the onClick function always stays the same
- ... `React.Fragment` to make react find a component again because otherwise a child would not have a unique id or sth similar

The child component is exported as:

`export default React.memo(TheChildComponent, compareEquality)` with

```
 const compareEquality = (prev, next) => {
      console.log(prev, next);
      return prev.isSelected === next.isSelected;
 }
```

Somehow the log line in `compareEquality` is never executed and therefore I know that `compareEquality` is never executed. I don't know why this is happening either.

I have checked all blogs, previous Stackoverflow questions etc. but could not yet find a way to prevent the child components from being rerendered every time that at least one component executes the `onClick` function and by doing that updated the `isSelected` state.

I would be very happy if someone could point me in the right direction or explain where my problem is coming from.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean `export default React.memo(TheChildComponent, compareEquality)`? `useMemo` isn't correct.

Comment: Whoops, yes it's React.memo and not useMemo. Just corrected it in the question. Thank you.

Comment: Can you try adding a second argument of `[]` to `useCallback`? Without a deps list, `useCallback` has no effect. (This doesn't explain why `compareEquality` isn't called, but it would remove the need for it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the only problem was neither `useCallback`, `useMemo` or anything similar.

In the render function of the parent component I did not directly use

```
return isSelected.map(...)
```

I included that part from a seperate, very simple component like this:

```
const Fields = () => {

     return isSelected.map((isFieldSelected, i) => (
       <TheChildComponent
            key={i}
            isSelected={isFieldSelected}
            onClick={onClick}
       />
     ));

};
```

That is where my problem was. When moving the code from the seperate component `Fields` into the return statement of the parent component the rerendering error vanished.

Still, thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah, good catch. Another way this issue should fix is if you wrote `const Fields = React.memo(() => { ... });`. (Assuming `Fields` is defined at the top level, not within another component.) I always wrap all components in `React.memo`.

Answer (score 2):

This code will actually generate a new `onClick` function every render, because `useCallback` isn't given a deps array:

```js
const onClick = useCallback((index) => {
     const newIsSelected = [...prev];
     newIsSelected[i] = !newIsSelected[i];
     return newIsSelected;
});
```

The following should only create one `onClick` function and re-use it throughout all renders:

```js
const onClick = useCallback((index) => {
     const newIsSelected = [...prev];
     newIsSelected[i] = !newIsSelected[i];
     return newIsSelected;
}, []);
```

Combined with vanilla `React.memo`, this should then prevent the children from re-rendering except when `isSelected` changes.  (Your second argument to `React.memo` should have also fixed this -- I'm not sure why that didn't work.)

As a side note, you can simplify this code:

```js
     <React.Fragment key={key}>
          <TheChildComponent
               isSelected={isFieldSelected}
               onClick={onClick}
          />
     </React.Fragment/>
```

to the following:

```js
          <TheChildComponent key={key}
               isSelected={isFieldSelected}
               onClick={onClick}
          />
```

(assuming you indeed only need a single component in the body of the `map`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the `deps` array but the problem still persists. (Updated the question as well)

Comment: Everything else in the code you posted looks good, so perhaps you'll need to post a link to the full codebase, e.g. in codesandbox.io

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I just found the error myself and posted the answer.